# find next instance of class from clicked table row

Tags: jquery, html

trying to show a hidden element when clicking a table row. Each row has an instance of this element with the same class name but I only want to show the one on the same row that is clicked. Here is the html structure

```
<table id="task-table">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><span class="icons"> i c o n </span>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><span class="icons"> i c o n </span>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><span class="icons"> i c o n </span>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is jquery

```
  $('#task-table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    $(this).next('.icons').show('fast');
  });
```

What am I doing wrong can anyone assist?

Comment: That code is inside a `$(document).ready (function{  });` isn't?

Comment: yes it is and I guess I should have tried to hide it in my question instead of showing since it already was visible. However, my real problem was addressing the element which swajak elegantly showed me how to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.next` will look at siblings after the `tr`. So, `.next('tr')` would give you a result, but not what you want. What you want is something like:

```
$(this).find('.icons').show('fast');
```

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8yx6P/2/

Comment: one thing can  achieve  in many ways your way is far simplier

Answer (score 1):

do like this

```
<table id="task-table">
  <tr id="1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><span class="icons_1"> i c o n </span>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="2">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><span class="icons_2"> i c o n </span>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="3">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><span class="icons_3"> i c o n </span>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

$('#task-table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

$('.icons_'+id).show('fast');
  });
```

see if that can help u

here working FIddle

http://jsfiddle.net/maree_chaudhry/TYCq3/

Comment: unfortunately I can not add "id" to the table rows